# What does the notation $[b_1,b_2]$ in M. Hochster's "Prime Ideal Structure in Commutative Rings" mean?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, notation

I'm reading the article

*M. Hochster*, [**Prime ideal structure in commutative rings**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=251026), *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **142** (1969), 43--60. Freely available [here on the journal's website](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X/).

But, I can not find the definition of the symbol "$[b_1 , b_2]$" in the proof of Theorem 4 (page 49, which is 7th page of the pdf).

Could someone explain what this notation means there?
Possibly it is explained somewhere in the paper, but I could not locate it.

Comment: Not sure how this is off-topic...I just took another look at the paper myself and am puzzling over what the notation is supposed to mean.  I can't tell for sure, but I think it is supposed to denote the subring generated by $b_1$ and $b_2$.

Comment: I agree with @EricWofsey it is not very clear. Normally I'd assume it is some kind of LCM but this does not quite seem to fit. I added a way to locate the document easily. It might have been still better to include the relevant part in the post, but then perhaps it is sufficient like this.

Comment: I am grateful for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess for what $[b_1,b_2]$ is supposed to mean is the subring of $A$ generated by $b_1$ and $b_2$.  However, even with this interpretation, there are some statements that aren't quite right (though as I recall, this particular paper has a lot of minor errors of this sort, so this shouldn't be too surprising).  Here is how I would rewrite the final three sentences of the proof of Theorem 4:

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2]\to A$ be the unique homomorphism sending $x_i$ to $b_i$ and let $I=(x_1,x_2)\subset\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2]$.  For any $z\in I$, $f(z)$ vanishes off of $d(b_1)\cup d(b_2)$, and its image restricted to $d(b_1)\cup d(b_2)$ is equal to its image restricted to the finite set $Y$.  Thus we need only find $z\in I$ such that $z\not\in f^{-1}(\phi(y))$ for each $y\in Y$, and then $c=f(z)$ will be an element of $(b_1,b_2)$ such that $d(c)=d(b_1)\cup d(b_2)$.  But each $f^{-1}(\phi(y))$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2]$ which does not contain $I$ (since every point of $Y$ is in $d(b_1)\cup d(b_2)$), and there are only finitely many of them, so by prime avoidance such a $z$ must exist.